# Noop function that returns first argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lodash

Is there a function that just returns the first arg? Similar to $.noop or angular.noop except that they return undefined. I am using jQuery, Angular, and lodash.

Comment: native type-specific constructors are a fast `k` replacement: `Boolean(true)`, `String('hello')`, `Number(22)`, etc. i don't think there is a native identity function in JS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In angular:

As dfsq said, in angular there is **[angular.identity](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.identity)**.

#### In lodash:

In lodash there is **[_.identity](https://lodash.com/docs#identity)**

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a function that just returns the first arg?

Yes, it's called [identity function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.identity).

```
angular.identity(1, 2, 3); // => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if one already exists but you can write one.

```
function myNoop() { return arguments[0]; }
```

Comment: I dislike defining global functions or defining the same function twice was my concern.

Comment: This won't define a global function, though, depending on your context. Namespacing this would be simple.

Comment: It's certainly bad form to use the `arguments` object, but it's not much slower than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

With es6 you can do `a=>a`

```
> (a=>a)(1,2,3) 
1
```